# Downloading a multi-file PDF

Tags: pdf, download, adobe-reader

Many of my school textbooks have PDF files online. However, they are a multiple-file PDFs that can be read in Adobe Reader. For an example of this, try opening one of the PDFs located [here](http://www.frankenmuth.k12.mi.us/education/components/docmgr/default.php?sectiondetailid=4960&PHPSESSID=2845dc1aa1fd92ae6543a8596d0c6e1a) in Adobe Reader. I want to download the entire textbook to read off of my Android device. Is there some script or utility I can utilize to download the entire textbook? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand. I see one PDF for each chapter or section, and they worked fine Preview and Safari (ie, not Adobe Reader).  Are you looking to combine these many files in into one?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please provide more information on what you're actually attempting to do, and what the problem you're having is.

Comment: @ChrisHerbert: When you open one of the PDFs in Adobe Reader, you see a bookmarks sidebar that links to the other PDF files. I'm wondering of there's any way to download all of the bookmarks' PDFs with a utility or script. I want to do this because not all of my textbooks that are online have downloads for each individual chapter (I can only access the other chapters through bookmarks with Adobe Reader). Here's a screenshot showing the bookmarks sidebar http://i.imgur.com/JlLsk.jpg

Comment: @DanielBeck: I want to know if I can use a script or utility to download all of a PDF file's bookmarks and combine them into one big PDF file. I want to do this because not all of my online textbooks have downloads for each individual chapter (the chapters are only available through one PDF's bookmarks). Here's a screenshot of Adobe Reader's bookmark sidebar http://i.imgur.com/JlLsk.jpg

Comment: I see.  Are you able to actually view the other chapters using those sidebar links?  They aren't working for me.

Comment: @ChrisHerbert: When I opened it in Adobe Acrobat X I was able to.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine PDF files using [FoxyUtils MergePDF](http://foxyutils.com/mergepdf/)

It's online and best of all FREE.  You will of course need to download them all first, and then combine them into one PDF using that site.

Answer (score 0):

To download all the pdf files together try DTA oneclick option on downthemall addon for firefox and use the pdf merger mentioned by viiron